# Python - Factory functions with different arguments

Tags: python, types, factory, type-hinting

I have logic in my application that requires me to create different variations of one specific class. These variations differ only by class properties.

If variation == "A", then some class properties need to be set to zero and others filled with the provided input, else if variation == "B", some other properties are zero etc.

It looks to me that the factory pattern is a perfect solution for this problem, but there is a complication I cannot find a solution for - every variation is expected to receive a **different number of arguments**. Basically, business logic knows that, let's say, property X of variation A is always 0, so function create_variation_a() should not expect X as argument.

I could just set argument X to a default value, but than other devs would not know if X needs to be provided or not without checking the code.

```
class Something:
    def __init__(self, one: int, two: int, three: int):
        self.one = one
        self.two = two
        self.three = three

def create_one(one: int) -> Something:
    return Something(one=one, two=0, three=0)

def create_two(one: int, two: int) -> Something:
    return Something(one=one, two=two, three=0)

def create_three(one: int, two: int, three: int) -> Something:
    return Something(one=one, two=two, three=three)

factory = {
    "one": create_one,
    "two": create_two,
    "three": create_three
}

myfunc1 = factory["one"]

# I want type checker to know that I only need to supply one
variation_one = myfunc1()

myfunc3 = factory["three"]

# I want type checker to know that I need to supply one, two and three
variation_three = myfunc3()
```

Comment: Why does `Factory` exist, rather than `Factory.get_func` be an ordinary function? You aren't using `cls` in the method.

Comment: All you've really done is replace an ordinary dictionary lookup: `d = {'one': create_one, ...}; myfunc1 = d.get('three')`.

Comment: you are right, but this is just an example. it could just be a function returning other functions or a dict[str, Callable[..., str]], but the problem would still remain

P.S. changed example

Comment: Type hints are for *static* type checking; static type checkers have no way of knowing which function `get_func` will return at runtime. They don't simulate code to see what an argument of `"three"` will result in. You can say that it will return a function with one of three types, but you can't use that information to know *which* type `myfunc1` will have.

Comment: That is, the return type can be `Callable[[str], str] | Callable[[str,str], str] | Callable[[str,str,str], str]`, but the type checker can't reduce that to a single constituent type  with `factory["one"]` alone. You need support for something like dependent types, in which types can depend on values.

Comment: Actually, now that you've actually replaced the function with a dict lookup, you can use `typing.TypedDict` to define a more specific type.

Comment: You should show an example of the actual variations you want to handle, not just your attempt. Otherwise this is a bit of an x-y problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `typing.TypedDict` to provide a more specifically typed `dict` that knows what type of value each specific key maps to.

```
from typing import TypedDict, Callable

class FactoryType(TypedDict):
    one: Callable[[str], str]
    two: Callable[[str, str], str]
    three: Callable[[str, str, str], str]


factory : FactoryType =  {'one': create_one, 'two': create_two, 'three': create_three}
```

---

This works because `TypedDict` is essentially one giant special case for handling argument-specific type narrowing for `dict.get`.

Comment: This is close to what I need. Can I somehow specify the exact function signature instead of Callable[[str, str, str], str] so that the IDE sees that, for example, "two" and "three" are expected? Sometimes it can be that "one" is not needed, only "two" and "three". Positional [str,str] is not very useful because, it's not obvious what those strings are

Comment: Basically can I do something like Callable[kwargs, str] and specify what those kwargs actually are?

Comment: Protocol might be the missing piece. Using this in the FactoryType instead of Callable actually tells which arguments are missing

class ThreeSignature(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, one: int, two: int, three: int) -> Something:
        ...

Comment: @AlexK. yes, if you need that sort of specificity, then you need to use a callable protocol.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `typing.overload` here:

```
import typing
from collections.abc import Callable

def create_one(one: str) -> str:
    return one


def create_two(one: str, two: str) -> str:
    return one + two


def create_three(one: str, two: str, three: str) -> str:
    return one + two + three

@typing.overload
def get_func(term: typing.Literal["one"]) -> Callable[[str], str]:
    ...
@typing.overload
def get_func(term: typing.Literal["two"]) -> Callable[[str, str], str]:
    ...
@typing.overload
def get_func(term: typing.Literal["three"]) -> Callable[[str, str, str], str]:
    ...
def get_func(term):
    if term == "one":
        return create_one
    elif term == "two":
        return create_two
    elif term == "three":
        return create_three
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"Did not recognize f{repr(term)}")


f = get_func("one")
f('foo')
f('foo', 'bar')

g = get_func("three")
g('foo', 'bar')
g('foo', 'bar', 'baz')
```

Then, using `mypy`:

```
(py311) juanarrivillaga-mbp16-2019:~ juanarrivillaga$ mypy test_typing.py
test_typing.py:37: error: Too many arguments  [call-arg]
test_typing.py:40: error: Too few arguments  [call-arg]
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```